# Date fields's disable date is not workingly correctly for 'j/nY' date format?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Expected output: in calendar date 03 jan 2019 and 11 jan 2019 should be disabled.

Actual Result: calendar shows multiple disable dates
i.e. 1st jan 2019

11 jan 2019

21 jan 2019

31 jan 2019

Here's my code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        name: 'from_date',
        format:'j/n/Y',
        disabledDates:["3/1/2019", "11/1/2019"],
        disabledDatesText:'holiday test',
        // maxValue: new Date()  // limited to the current date or prior
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'To',
        name: 'to_date',
        value: new Date()  // defaults to today
    }]
});
```

result image:
[image: result image]

Comment: which version you are using of ExtJS ?

Comment: @NarendraJadhav ExtJS 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Uhmm.. Seems a bug related to the `j` format or to the regex used for validating date formats.. Anyway, since the `disabledDate` values are strings used for building dynamic regular expressions, you can use the `^` metacharacter as workaround for forcing the first number to be correctly matched according to `j` format:

```
disabledDates:['^1/1/2019','^8/1/2019']
```

Tested with ExtJS 6.6 and 6.2 Classic Toolkit.

[image]

Comment: Worked for 'j/n/Y' date format but not working for other date formats. I used multiple date format for the calendar. Can you please suggest a common solution which is work for all date formats in the calendar. @hannibal

Comment: @SachinMore which version and toolkit of ExtJS are U using  ?

Comment: ExtJS 2.4 version